# Problem with json data source on ui autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a problem with my code. I receive data via ajax and it works, but the problem is that when I try to search for an element and all the elements appear so the search does not work properly.

JS code :

```js
let marque_id =$("#marque_id").val();
    $( "#grp_name" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url:"abonne/ajax_get_grp_autorisation",
                method:"POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    marque_id : id_marque
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( data );
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            // Set selection
            $('#grp_name').val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
            $('#id_grp_selected').val(ui.item.id); // save selected id to input
            return false;
        } 
    });
```

PHP code :

```
$data = array();
while($line = mysqli_fetch_object($liste_grp) ){
    $data[] = array("label"=>$line->grp_nom,"value"=>$line->grp_nom ,"id"=>$line->groupement_id);
}  
echo json_encode($data);
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhBci.jpg)

Comment: Please add your actual query

Comment: you talk about mysql query ?

Comment: What is `id_marque`? This does not appear to contain the `request.term`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should send the text you are searching for to ajax request so your autocomplete function should be

```
let marque_id =$("#marque_id").val();
    $( "#grp_name" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url:"abonne/ajax_get_grp_autorisation",
                method:"POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    marque_id : id_marque , 
                    term: request.term       
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( data );
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            // Set selection
            $('#grp_name').val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
            $('#id_grp_selected').val(ui.item.id); // save selected id to input
            return false;
        } 
    });
```

request.term is your search text and in your example it is group text

and also you need to modify your mysql query and add condition (like)
for example

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE colum LIKE '%" . $_POST['term'] . "%'");
```

and finally you can check  https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: OP is not using `mysql`, but is using `mysqli`. Also this would open it up to SQL Injection.

Comment: That is only example to show him what I mean about like word  but in his code he should using pdo and using bind function to prevent SQL injection

Comment: thanks a lot i found another solution i use tokenInput and it's work http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Answer (score 0):

I would advise the following jQuery:

```
$( "#grp_name" ).autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url:"abonne/ajax_get_grp_autorisation",
      method:"POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        marque_id: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
        response(data);
      }
    });
  },
  select: function (event, ui) {
    // Set selection
    $('#grp_name').val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
    $('#id_grp_selected').val(ui.item.id); // save selected id to input
    return false;
  } 
});
```

This is a small change. This will send the `request.term` to your PHP Script. For example, if the user types "gro", this will be sent to your script and would be accessed via:

```
$_POST['marque_id']
```

This would assume your SQL Query is something like:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '?%'");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['marque_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$liste_grp = $stmt->get_result();
$data = array();
while($line = $liste_grp->fetch_assoc()) {
  $data[] = array(
    "label" => $line['grp_nom'],
    "value" => $line['grp_nom'],
    "id" => $line['groupement_id']
  );
}
$stmt->close();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

This uses the [MySQLi Prepared Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php), and will help prevent SQL Injection. I also included the JSON Header as good practice. The result of search `"gro"` would be something like:

```
[
  {
    "label": "GROUPE DATAPNEU TEST",
    "value": "GROUPE DATAPNEU TEST",
    "id": 1
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys i found a solution it works better 
i used tokeninput with many options

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeni

```
$.ajax({
        url:"ajax_get_societe_authorisation",
        method:"POST",
        scriptCharset: "iso-8859-1",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            marque_id : id_marque
        },
        success: function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#soc_name").tokenInput(data
        ,{
            tokenLimit: 1,
            hintText: "Recherche une société par son nom",
            noResultsText: "Aucune société trouvé",
            searchingText: "Recherche en cours ...",
            onAdd: function (data) {
                $("#soc_id").val(data.id);
            },
            onDelete: function (item) {
                $("#soc_id").val("");
            }
        }

    );
    }
    });
```